# Checkboxes and radio buttons with labels not firing addEventListener functions

Tags: javascript

Somehow the labels on my page are keeping the radio buttons and checkboxes from being clicked.

I have read just about every post I can find on this and cannot figure out why this isn't working for me.

There are a number of checkboxes and radio buttons on my page, but none of them work. When I remove the labels the functions work fine. I even created a test checkbox to try and isolate the issue but this still does not work.

```js
document.getElementById("myCheck").addEventListener("change", function() {
     console.log("working")
});
```

```html
     <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="myCheck">
     <label for="myCheck">Checkbox</label>
```

I have also tried putting the input inside the label tags, but this also does not work.

Comment: Seems like the snippet code above works, does it work for you? On your website, make sure you aren't obstructing the input check button with the label. For example the label could have a width that covers the checkbox, making it unable to function.

Comment: Ah. You got it. Someone else's css was setting the labels to z-index 2, covering the checkboxes and radios. However I thought that clicking on labels was supposed to click the radios and checkboxes also?

Comment: I'm not too sure about that, I guess both elements must have the same z-index for best accessibility.

Comment: So I moved the labels to z-index 0, and changed the opacity of the radio and checkboxes to 0 so they don't show up. My functions fire when I click on the boxes themselves, but not when I click on the labels... I feel like this is supposed to work.